# compiler plugins not loaded

Tags: vim

i tried to use this python compiler plugin to be able to "compile" a py script and see the errors in qucikfix windows and jump directly to the linenumers.

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1439

i placed it in /compiler/python.vim

but: the script is not loaded when i open a python file. even :filetype detect doesnt help.
(according to :scriptnames)

i also tried to put the stuff into _vimrc. but it is overwritten by some other stuff thats useless. i dont know where it comes from i searched all plugin directories but there is no plugin that does set makeprg and errorformat!

im lost. plz help.

thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Compiler-plugins are never loaded automatically. You'll have to load it explicitly with `:compiler python`.

Answer (score 3):

you could add this to your filetype.vim file:

```
autocmd! BufRead,BufNewFile *.py compiler python
```

Comment: The exclamation mark is dangerous. If he has a filetype.vim, he probably already have some `autocmd` there, which would be cleared with this.